# Haskell Scheme Environment

Tags: haskell, scheme

I am working on a class project and am running into issues concerning adding an environment to a Scheme programming language.
there are two main files that I am working with, main.hs and Evaluation.hs
main takes in the argument from the user and passes a parsed string to a run function. I need to add an environment to the evaluation portion of the program so that I can start defining variables using lambda and let.

```
type Env = [(String, Datum)]

run ::   Env -> Datum -> Maybe String
run = fmap printDatum . eval_maybe

printDatum :: Datum -> String
printDatum = pretty 80 . ppd

eval_maybe :: Env -> Datum -> Maybe Datum
eval_maybe env = forgetError . eval env

data Result = Good Datum | Bad Error

forgetError :: Result -> Maybe Datum
forgetError (Good r) = Just r
forgetError _        = Nothing
```

I have tried to implement an environment straight into the evaluation function and bypass run.  Tried to do the same with the eval_maybe function.  All my attempts have made me backtract the environment to the main.  I cannot change anything beyond the run function in the main.

I want to be able to implement the environment in the Evaluation code without having to change run.  All my attempts to do so have gotten errors.
My latest has been to try a do function in eval_maybe and load an environment before the eval function is called.

The error Haskell is giving me is:

```
run :: Datum -> Env -> Maybe String
run = fmap printDatum . eval_maybe []

src\Main.hs:16:7: error:
* Couldn't match type Datum' with [(String, Datum)]'
Expected type: Datum -> Env -> Maybe String
Actual type: Evaluation.Env -> Datum -> String
* In the expression: fmap printDatum . eval_maybe
In an equation for `run': run = fmap printDatum . eval_maybe
|
16 | run = fmap printDatum . eval_maybe
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\Main.hs:16:25: error:
* Couldn't match type Maybe Datum' with Datum'
Expected type: Evaluation.Env -> Datum -> Datum
Actual type: Evaluation.Env -> Datum -> Maybe Datum
* In the second argument of (.)', namely eval_maybe'
In the expression: fmap printDatum . eval_maybe
In an equation for `run': run = fmap printDatum . eval_maybe
|
16 | run = fmap printDatum . eval_maybe
```

Comment: Please format your post so all code and error messages are properly readable. (In doubt, just put them in code boxes, ctrl+k.) And it's confusing... you have two different definitions of the `run` function? And you also seem to have to different definitions of the `Env` type in the modules.

Answer (score 1):

Your types don't match up in `run`. You've declared that `run :: Env -> Datum -> Maybe String`. Let's look at the types of the four functions in `run`.

```hs
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
printDatum :: Datum -> String
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
eval_maybe :: Env -> Datum -> Maybe Datum
```

Let us next consider how the definition of run is parsed:

```hs
run = fmap printDatum . eval_maybe
run = ((.) (fmap printDatum)) eval_maybe
```

Now we can start type matching by evaluating types of larger and larger subexpressions, starting with `fmap printDatum`. I will line up corresponding types so you can see how this process works. From the first row of each set to the second, each type variable must always refer to the same type, and vice-versa, and when we fill in a slot in both lines, an argument can be applied successfully

```hs
     printDatum ::              (Datum -> String)
fmap            :: Functor f => (a     -> b     ) -> f a     -> f b
fmap            ~  Functor f => (Datum -> String) -> f Datum -> f String
```

Now we apply `printDatum` to our specialized `fmap` and repeat on a larger subexpression:

```
    (fmap printDatum) :: Functor f =>  f Datum -> f String
(.)                   ::              (b       -> c  )      -> (a -> b      ) -> (a -> c       )
(.)                   ~  Functor f => (f Datum -> f String) -> (a -> f Datum) -> (a -> f String)


(.) (fmap printDatum)            :: Functor f => (a   -> f Datum               ) -> a -> f String
                      eval_maybe ::              (Env -> (Datum -> Maybe Datum))
(.) (fmap printDatum)             ~ ???
```

We've run into a problem because `(Datum -> Maybe Datum)` doesn't unify with `f Datum`, so the argument `eval_maybe` cannot be successfully applied to the function `(.) (fmap printDatum)`.

In summary, assuming that `printDatum` and `eval_maybe` each have the right type, you cannot solve the issue without rewriting `run`, because that's where the problem lies.